# How to Publish an Existing .NET Core Web App to AWS Lambda

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I successfully published a .net core project using the AWS project template for functions and serverless web apps as well.

Now is there any way to publish my existing .net core web app which is created with a normal .NET Core Web App template?

I did try to publish it but there is no option for Publishing to AWS for that project.

Now is there any way to publish my existing .net core web app which is created with a normal .NET Core Web App template?

I did try to publish it but there is no option for Publishing to AWS for that project.